# Android keyboard with browser-like spell checking

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

I've used both the Samsung and Google keyboards, but none of them do spell checking the way I prefer. What annoys me is that either they auto-correct or they don't show that a word is misspelled at all.

On my desktop I use Firefox, which has built in spell checking that works the way I like it to. If I write a word that's not in the dictionary, it's marked with a red line. If I agree, I can right-click the word to get a list of suggested words. Sometimes I write words that are not in any dictionary, and I don't want these automatically edited if it's intentional.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

I want to have similar functionality when typing on my phone. I mostly use the keyboard for typing in chats and when browsing the web.

[image: Samsung keyboard]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the Samsung keyboard can underline words, but only does this for marking words that have been auto-corrected. I tested this in both Messages and Facebook Messenger.

#### Requirements

1. Supports Android 4.2.2.
2. No auto-correct, or ability to disable it.
3. Misspelled words are marked (e.g. the red jagged line in Firefox).
4. Click on a misspelled word to get suggestions from dictionary.
5. Costs no more than $3.

I like the support in the Samsung keyboard for using multiple dictionaries at once because I often mix Swedish and English when I type. This is not required, but a big plus.

Comment: I could be wrong,  but I'm pretty sure that keyboard apps can't make red jagged lines in other applications. I think it would be up to whatever app you use the keyboard in to implement this feature.

Comment: @hhaslam11 See my edit. I can't tell whether this functionality is in the applications or in the keyboard, but the fact that it looks exactly the same for two applications from different companies tells me that it's in the keyboard.

Comment: Auto-correction is part of the keyboard apps. Those normally make use of a system-wide dictionary, while some also provide their own. AFAIK, some also use their own algorithms (and sometimes even dictionaries) for that. But I doubt this feature can be altered/extended by the user for a given keyboard app (here: Samsung keyboard), so if you want "different behavior", you will have to try [different keyboards](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) to find one that suits your needs.